# Make a file availabe on all nodes

Tags: c, mpi, qsub

I'm writing a MPI application that takes a filename as an argument and tries to read from the file using regular C functions. I run this application on several nodes of a cluster by using `qsub`, which in turn uses `mpiexec`.

The application runs just fine on a local node where the file is. For this I just call `mpiexec` directly:

```
mpiexec -n 4 ~/my_app ~/input_file.txt
```

But when I submit it with `qsub` to be run on other nodes of the cluster, the file reading part fails. The application errors at `fopen` call -- it can't open the file (likely because it's not present).

The question is, how do I make the file available to all nodes? I have looked over `qsub` manpage and couldn't fine anything relevant.

Comment: The usual way to do this in production clusters is to have a filesystem shared between compute and login nodes using Lustre, NFS or a similar protocol.  If that was mounted in, say, /lustre, all of the ranks in your MPI job should be able to get at your file under /lustre/input_file.txt.  Are you sure your cluster admins haven't set up something like that?

Comment: Contacted admins, got it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Vanilla Gorilla doesn't need an answer any more?  However, let's consider the case of a pathological system with no parallel file system and a file system available only at one node.  There is a way in ROMIO (a very common MPI-IO implementation) to achieve your goal:

[how can i transfer file from one proccess to all other with mpi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649901/how-can-i-transfer-file-from-one-proccess-to-all-other-with-mpi/10419349#10419349)